# Local build agent not picking up new build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild

I have a TFS server on a remote machine, and succesfully installed a build agent on my own machine. The connection between these works as intended:

[image]

The agent is online, and running succesfully. However, when I try to queue a build, I get this error:

[image]

I think the solution lies in this text:

```
No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
msbuild
visualstudio
DotNetFramework
Agent.Version -gtVersion 1.98.1
```

Since I have MSBuild, VS2017 and .Net installed on my machine, I ***think*** it's the Agent.Version that's causing problems. But how do I check what version of the agent I have running? I followed [this](https://www.benday.com/2018/01/11/howto-install-tfs2018-vsts-build-agent-on-windows-server-core/) guide to installing the build agent. And where can I find other versions of the build agent online? The MS site doesn't seem to offer download options for older/newer versions of the build agent.

Comment: You're guessing right now. You can get a definitive answer by looking at the `Capabilities` tab of your agent, from the Agent Queue or Agent Pool view. The Agent Pool view will also have a link to download the correct agent version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed the agent according your link so the version should be fine (because you downloaded the agent from your TFS).

Go to Agent Pools page, then check the agent's Capabilities. 
[image]
Look after the the version of MSBuild/VS/.Net, maybe on the agent computer the right version not installed.

Another option - the agent didn't recognize the installed stuff so you can add it to the agent's capabilities manually by click on "Add capability":

[image]

Comment: This was it, thank you. For some reason, the `visualstudio` capability was missing. The first time I installed the agent it worked fine, but for some reason the next day TFS decided the agent wasn't good enough anymore. We'll chalk that up to TFS being TFS.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after upgrading Azure DevOps On Premise from 2019 RC2 to 2019 Release.  After the upgrade I had to download the new Build Agent from the Azure server and install the new version on my build agents.  After upgrading the build agents they began reporting the correct capabilities.

Comment: A me too testimony is not an answer. Wile your remark is relevant and in line with the accepted answer, it should go as a comment and not as an answer.